# Removing duplicates from a sorted list (New Approach)

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is my program for removing duplicates from a sorted linked list. I am traversing from the head node of the linked list and using temp1 variable, I am checking whether there are any duplicates of the same value. If we find a data which is different from the current node, then we link that to current node and make it current node and repeat the process.
Here is the question:-
https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/

```
ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* head) {
    ListNode *curr=head,*temp1,*forw;
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
       //temp1 checks for next distinct element
        temp1=curr->next;
        while(temp1!=NULL)
        {
           //checking if the value at temp1 is distinct from current
            if(temp1->val!=curr->val)
            {
                forw=temp1; //stored the distinct value in forw for reference to curr
                break;
            }
            temp1=temp1->next;
        }
        curr->next=forw; // linked the distinct value to current
        curr=curr->next;
    }
return head;
}
```

But, the program is giving TLE(Time Limit Excedeed) Error.I have dry runned the code and it's working fine for me. I think i am missing some edge. Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: *But, the program is giving TLE Error* -- A Two Line Element set error?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) for basic test case

Comment: Damn. I had my money on *The Littlest Elephant.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have UB for list of one element, as `forw` is then used uninitialized.

(that UB should probably do, in your case, infinite loop, so TLE).

Comment: Thanks for helping a budding programmer